# Moderator Pro Tempore Elections on Pets.SE?

Tags: discussion, voting, moderation

On pets we currently have [4 moderators](https://pets.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) all are active on the site and cover multiple levels of expertise and goegrphical locations.

There is new [Experimental Pro Tempore elections](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/314459/experimenting-with-pro-tempore-elections) for sites still in Beta.

While I don't see where we **NEED** to have moderator elections here.  I do believe that [Voting is an important part of community engagement. By denying moderator elections to sites that are successful with well defined scopes and strong communities, we are disenfranchising the community.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/293477/217279)

New voting would not impact any of the existing moderators.  If there was a vote, it would be for an additional moderator.  Historically we have had some moderator turn over, as can be seen by [awards of the Constable
badge.](https://pets.stackexchange.com/help/badges/85/constable)

You can read more about [Moderator Pro Tempore,here](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/07/27/moderator-pro-tempore/)

So I propose this question, for the near term (*next year or so*) to the pets.se communitie "**Would we like to hold elections for 1 Moderator Pro Tempore?**"

Comment: To be clear, I have no issue with having an extra mod. It's a fun site and a good mod team. I think we need to focus on continuing to build up our regular user base and encourage chat and meta activity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure the site's activity warrants a fifth moderator. Given that we have (I think) European, American and Australian moderators, the coverage is good as well.

Don't let that stop you though. Elections are always fun :)

Comment: I tend to agree with this. We need to keep building up our regular user base and encourage chat and meta activity. To be clear, I have no issue with having an extra mod. It's a fun site and a good mod team.

Comment: Oh Stack Overflow elections are erm... fun isn't quite the word I'd use to descibe them. Harrowning? :D

Comment: @YvetteColomb I had the hope that elections on here could be pretty drama-free. :fingers crossed:

Comment: Oh definitely. We're a pretty chilled site.